# Login and redirect after Logout PHP

Tags: php

Here is my db.classes

```
public function login($un, $pw)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbh,"select username, password from users where username='$un' and password='$pw'");

        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count==1){
            header("location:home.php");
        }
        else {
            echo 
            "<script type='text/javascript'>

            alert('LOG-IN FAILED!');

            </script>";

            echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="index.php" </script>';
        }
    }
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?PHP
include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();   

    if(isset($_POST['subBtn']))
        {
            $un = $g->clean($_POST["uname"]);
            $pw = $g->clean($_POST["pass"]);
            $g->login($un, $pw);
        }

$g->close();    
?>
```

Here is my logout button

```
<div id="footer">
    <li id="Login"><a href="index.php">Log Out</a></li>
</div>
```

How can i prevent the user from going back to the previous pages without logging in again after logging out?

Comment: check for session is null or not

Comment: while login set the Session and logout means unset the session if session is empty redirect to index.php page

Comment: http://www.makeitsimple.co.in/PHP_loginexmp.php

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
session_start();
```

at the very beginning of your script.

When the Login is successful you can set a Session like

```
$_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

or even store userdata like his name or ID for later operations.

Then on every page you want to secure just add

```
if($_SESSION['login'] !== true) header("location:index.php");
```

And to logout you can either unset the session or just set it to false

```
$_SESSION['login'] = false;
unset($_SESSION['login']);
```

This can be optimized to your needs as far as you want....

http://krisnaordinary.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/creating-a-simple-login-logout-session-using-php/

This article seems to go a bit deeper into Sessions...

Answer (score -1):

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;

include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();   

if(isset($_POST['subBtn'])){
    $un = $g->clean($_POST["uname"]);
    $pw = $g->clean($_POST["pass"]);
    $g->login($un, $pw);
}

$g->close();    
?>
```

On login : set `logged_in` to true (if credentials are ok)

```
public function login($un, $pw){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbh,"select username, password from users where username='$un' and password='$pw'");

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1){
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header("location:home.php");
    } else {
       $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('LOG-IN FAILED!');</script>";
       echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="index.php" </script>';
       die();
    }
}
```

In 'home.php' :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
//...
```

on logout :
EDITED to answer the question in the comment :

Logout button :

```
<div id="footer">
    <li id="Login"><a href="index.php?logout=1">Log Out</a></li>
</div>
```

In index.php (at beginning):

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1){
   $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
   header('location: index.php');
   die();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All of your pages that are not public should check the session before anything.

Example:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user_id']<1)
    die('You must login'); //Or redirect from here
```

This will prevent them from hitting back. You may also need to send some cache headers as well:

```
<?PHP
header ("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT",true);
header ("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",true);
header ("Pragma: no-cache",true);
```

Usually the caching headers aren't needed, but may help if the issue persists.